# PHP - Is it possible to retrieve an image without saving it as a file?

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, upload

I am currently learning the CodeIgniter framework and would like some help with uploading/displaying images.

I am working with a customer table in which there is an 'avatar' field, which, as the name suggests, is a unique image which is reserved for and represents its respective customer.

*I ask in this fashion because  know that in C# and SQL Server, you can convert an image to "Binary" and save it in the DB; and likewise read the same "Binary" from the database, and convert it into an image.*

I am wondering if the above, or something similar, is also possible in PHP...

After some research I see that most people are using the file location of the image, *which I do not want to do.* What's the point of type "BLOB" if I can simply save the location of the image instead?

If I am mistaken or misunderstanding any concepts please to clarify respectfully, that I may learn.

---

**TLDR**;

How do I go about saving/retrieving an image to and from the database without concerning myself with its file location? If this is impossible, then what's the point of "BLOB"?

I am working on WAMP and am using mysqld.

Sincere help is appreciated, thank you all in advance.

Comment: what type of database are you using?

Comment: I'm currently just working with localhost WAMP, mysqld, phpmyadmin.

Comment: You basically need to use `fopen` to get the data from the file and send it to your MySQL db. See if this helps http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/mysql-tutorials/uploading-files-to-mysql-database.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Blobs are ways of storing files and file systems in databases. Creating an image Blob will store the file in a container in your database. It is also a convenient way of packaging a number of files into a single database object. Blobs are not very widely used since it is generally simpler to access the file system containing the content directly.

Unsurprisingly most developers don't seem to enjoy the concept of 'filesystems inside of databases'.

Comment: So you suggest storing the image's location and simply fetching it from there would be better? :P